# Algorithm2e does not properly indent inside algorithmic

Tags: overleaf, algorithm2e, algorithmic

I have the below MWE. The desired output is one tab indentation of lines. Do you see what is wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{geometry,nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}
  {\ALG@tlm\z@}{\leftmargin\z@\ALG@tlm\z@}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetArgSty{textnormal}
\SetAlgoLined
\begin{algorithmic}
    \Function{Initialization}{$A$,$B$,$C$}
    
    \State{\For{$i \gets 1$ \KwTo $N$,}{\For{$i \gets 1$ \KwTo $nPop$,}{ $A \gets B$\;} \For{$j \gets{} 1$ \KwTo $M$,}{$C\gets 5$\;}}}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
 \caption{Initialization}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot use `algorithm2e` and `algpseudocode` together. Choose either.

Comment: Makes sense. I just like the vertical lines but also the function name style of algpseudocode.